# Removing all rectangles in rectangle array(LIBGDX)

Tags: libgdx

Hi guys so I created a simple game with a flying helicopter in which you need to dodge the missiles. I want to remove all missiles that are created in the screen if gameOver boolean is true. What is happening is it's only removed if the helicopter dies because of hitting the missile, but if it dies by hitting the ground the "game over" message shows but the missiles are not removed!

I tried using

```
if(heliR.overlaps(missiles)){gameOver=true; Iter.remove; }
```

But like what I said all missiles are only removed if I died by hitting missile, can anyone help me in this?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void create()
{
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera=new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false,800,480);
    restart=TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    click=TimeUtils.nanoTime();

    //fonts
    font=new BitmapFont();
    font1=new BitmapFont();
    font2=new BitmapFont();
    font.setColor(Color.RED);
    font1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    font2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    font.setScale(3);
    font1.setScale(1);
    font2.setScale(2);

    //score
    points=0;
    lastScore=TimeUtils.nanoTime();

    //background
    Texture texture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png"));
    background=new TextureRegion(texture,0,0,800,480);

    //logo
    logo=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("logo.png"));
    logoR=new Rectangle();
    logoR.x=230;
    logoR.y=240;
    logoR.width=230;
    logoR.height=100;

    //helicopter
    heli=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("helicopter.png"));
    heliR=new Rectangle();
    heliR.x=280;
    heliR.y=400;
    heliR.width=heli.getWidth()-15;
    heliR.height=heli.getHeight()-15;

    //Sounds
    heliSound=Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("helicopter.wav"));
    heliLanding=Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("helicopter_landing.wav"));
    collision=Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("collision.wav"));

    //missile
    missileImg=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("missile.png"));
    missiles=new Array<Rectangle>();
}

public void spawnMissile(){
    Rectangle missile=new Rectangle();
    missile.y=MathUtils.random(60,400);
    missile.x=mX;
    missile.width=missileImg.getWidth()-15;
    missile.height=missileImg.getHeight()-10;
    missiles.add(missile);
    lastMissile=TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    velocity=250;
}

@Override
public void render()
{        
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(background,backGroundX-800,0,800,480);
    batch.draw(background,backGroundX,0,800,480);
    batch.draw(heli,heliR.x,heliR.y);
    if(justStart==false && gameOver==false){
        font2.draw(batch,"Points:"+points,345,480);}
    //missile
    for(Rectangle missile: missiles){
        batch.draw(missileImg,missile.x,missile.y);
    }

    //game over
    if(gameOver==true){
        heliR.y=250;
        heliR.x=330;
        font.draw(batch,"Game Over",280,400);
        font1.draw(batch,"[Long press on the screen to restart]",275,230);
        font1.draw(batch,"Your points:"+points,348,250);
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            longClick+=1;

            if(longClick==35){
            gameOver=false;
            points=0;
            longClick=0;
            heliR.y=300;
            heliR.x=30;
            }
        }else{
            if(TimeUtils.nanoTime()- click > 2000000){longClick=0;}
        }
    }
    //starting game
    if(justStart==true){
        heliR.y=250;
        heliR.x=330;
        font2.draw(batch,"Touch the screen to start",230,230);
        batch.draw(logo,logoR.x,logoR.y);
        font1.draw(batch,"Developed by:Monzterr",5,15);

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            justStart=false;
            heliR.y=300;
            heliR.x=30;
        }
    }
    batch.end();
    //game physics
    if(justStart==false&&gameOver==false){
        //missile
        if(TimeUtils.nanoTime()-lastMissile > 1000000000){spawnMissile();}
        Iterator <Rectangle> iter=missiles.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Rectangle missile= iter.next();
            missile.x-=velocity*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(missile.x<=-10){iter.remove();}
            if(missile.overlaps(heliR)){
                gameOver=true;
                collision.play();
            }
            if(gameOver==true){
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
        //background
        backGroundX= backGroundX-100*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(backGroundX<=0){
            backGroundX=800;
        }
        //score
        if(TimeUtils.nanoTime()-lastScore>2000000000){
            points=points+1;

            lastScore=TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        }
        //gravity
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            heliR.y+=5;
            //heliLanding.play();
        }else{
            heliR.y-=5;
            //heliLanding.pause();
            }
    }
    //borders
    if(heliR.y>=400){
        heliR.y=250;
    }
    if(heliR.y<=56){
        heliR.y=56;
        gameOver=true;
        mX=800;
        collision.play();
    }
}

@Override
public void dispose()
{
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height)
{
}

@Override
public void pause()
{
}

@Override
public void resume()
{
}
```

Sorry for messy code I just started learning programming last week.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if **gameOver == true** twice - one on the (almost) beginning of the **render()** method

```
    //game over
    if(gameOver==true){
        heliR.y=250;
        ...
```

and second time under following condition

```
    //game physics
    if(justStart==false&&gameOver==false){
    ...
```

but you are removing iterator only in the second one

```
    if(gameOver==true){
            iter.remove();
        }
```

fixing it should fix your problem. Consider also do you need two checks if **gameOver** is true (I believe you not - you can handle both situations in the first one)

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `gameOver` to true in the middle of looping through all your enemies, and only removing them from within the loop, so only the enemies *after* the one that caused the game over will be removed. Replace `iter.remove()` with break (to jump out of the loop which is now unnecessary to finish). And then add a line after the loop:

```
if (gameOver) missiles.clear();
```

This removes everything from the array.